# SQL, where clause is not applied

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm using mysql 5.1

Here is my request, 
I want to count the number of users who are between 0 to 14 years old and with an enable account.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT user.id ) AS user
FROM profile, user
WHERE (
profile.age
BETWEEN 0 
AND 14
)
AND user.enabled =1
```

The `user.enabled=1` condition is working, but not the `profile.age BETWEEN 0 AND 14`

Comment: Please provide examples of how this is not working.  What is the data type of `age`?  And why are you joining the tables using an implicit `cross join` instead of an explicit `join`?

Comment: Is `profile.age` an integer?

Comment: My tables user have 800 entries, and there are 759 enabled accounts. My request returns 759. Age column is an integer.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing it down? like removing the enabled condition, or the user table?

Comment: The request `SELECT COUNT(id) as user FROM profile WHERE age BETWEEN 0 AND 14` works

Comment: Why are you storing an age?  Do you update it daily? Store a date of birth and calculate it.

Comment: What about `profile.enabled =1`?

Comment: @njk I'm not the DB designer... I can't change the DB architecture.

Comment: @Nick The request `SELECT COUNT(id) as user FROM profile, user WHERE user.enabled=1` works too.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you develop the 'And why are you joining the tables using an implicit cross join instead of an explicit join'. I have to make a JOIN to execute my query?

Comment: You are selecting from two tables, `profile` and `user`.  However, you have no logical condition connecting the tables.  Normally this would be something like `from profile p join user u on p.userid = u.userid` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't joining the 2 tables together therefore you are simply running the cartesian product of the two. You need to join them by a common key.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT user.id ) AS user
FROM profile join user on user.id=profile.user_id
WHERE (
profile.age
BETWEEN 0 
AND 14
)
AND user.enabled =1
```